# Why does memory go down after I take a heap dump?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-dump, wildfly-9, jmap

I am running a web application with `WildFly 9` and I've allocated `X GB` of memory. Over a period of time the memory gets accumulated and I run the `jmap` utility to collect the heap dump for analysing the memory utilization.

When I do this, the memory consumed by the `java.exe` comes down from `X` to `X-Y GB`. Sometimes the `Y` amounts to `GBs` of memory.

Why does this happen? If this chunk of memory is marked to be cleared, why doesn't GC clear it?

Comment: It isn't "marked to be cleared" until GC happens. There is a full garbage collection before the heap dump is taken.

Comment: And why doesn't full GC happen when I don't take the heap dump?

Comment: It depends on the garbage collector that you're using. It hasn't happened because the GC has decided that it doesn't need to happen.

Comment: Understood but without GC happening, the memory is going high and OOM occurs. Is it recommended / possible to initiate a full GC, manually?

Comment: Which options you used with jmap command?

Comment: jmap -dump:file=FileName.hprof <pid>